# UpdateOne, ReplaceOne, FindOneAndReplace - patternmatch, but no upd data

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I'm Using Mongo Go Adapter: github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/

I'm trying different patterns but none of them working for me.

//ref struct

```
type userbase struct {
    Name  string `bosn:"Name"`
    Coins int    `bson:"Coins"`
}
```

//ref code, it's updating _id, but not updating a value

```
filter := bson.M{"name": "Dinamis"}
update := bson.D{{"$inc", bson.M{"Coins": 1}}}
db := Client.Database("Nothing").Collection("dataUser")
db.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update)
```

//update filters that i also used

```
update := bson.D{{"$inc", bson.D{{"Coins", 1},}},}
```

//simple ways was tryed also

```
update := &userbase{name, amount} //should i try *userbase{} ?
```

//Also i'm tryed

```
ReplaceOne() 
FindOneAndReplace()
FindOneAndUpdate()
```

it's hard to dig deeper b-cuz of luck of actual documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/go/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Wan Bachtiar for answering this in official MongoDB-go-adapter group.

> By default queries in MongoDB is case sensitive on the field name. In
>   your struct you defined the field to be Name, but in your filter to
>   specify name. This would result in no documents matching the query
>   predicates for the the update operation. For example, if you have a
>   document as below:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("..."), "Name": "Dinamis", "Coins": 1 }
```

> You can perform an update to increment the number of Coins using below
>   snippet:

```
collection := client.Database("Nothing").Collection("dataUser")
filter := bson.M{"Name": "Dinamis"}
update := bson.D{{"$inc", bson.M{"Coins": 1}}}
result, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)
```

> Also, note that you have a typo on the bson tag in your struct. It’s
>   supposed to be bson:"Name" not bosn:"Name". You may find Query
>   Documents as a useful reference (Select the Go tab to show examples in
>   Go)
>
> Regards, Wan.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow. Here's the link to the post in group as well. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-go-driver/lcpnxzraZVU